# Guava: HashBasedTable that keeps insertion order?

Tags: java, guava

I am in a need of a way to keep two keys for a value - exactly what Guavan's HashBasedTable does . The issue is that it does not keep the insertion order when iterating over values. Is there any elegant solution to get it working? It doesn't have to be Guava, but I wouldn't want to bloat my project with dependencies.

I am trying to use mentioned ImmutableTable - and I haven't found any example. I get NPE everywhere when building a table like that:

```
ImmutableTable<String, String, AbstractUnit> units;
ImmutableTable.Builder<String, String, AbstractUnit> builder =        units.builder();
builder.put(unit1.getType(), unit1.getName(), unit1);
...
units = builder.build();
```

I will get NPE when gettinb units.values(). Also, will I be able to modify values of AbstractUnit in the table?

Comment: [issue 497](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=497) is relevant

Answer (score 11):

You can specify the back-end map structure for your table. Specifying a LinkedHashMap will maintain the insertion order.

```
 Table<String,String,AbstractUnit> units = Tables.newCustomTable(new LinkedHashMap<>(), LinkedHashMap::new);
```

I tried using the ImmutableMap as described by @Louis Wasserman and it was doing natural ordering instead.

Answer (score 2):

`ImmutableTable` will maintain insertion order, like all the other immutable collections.

Comment: Looks interesting, but I couldn't find any examples of usage. I will put items just once into the table, do I have to call .build() on the table every time I want to access anything?

Comment: No, that would be silly.  Just create the table with an `ImmutableTable.Builder`, call `build()` when you're done adding items to the table, and then store the resulting `ImmutableTable` wherever.

Comment: I have some doubts about using it properly - and I haven't found any example. I get NPE everywhere when building a table like that:

    ImmutableTable<String, String, AbstractUnit> units;
   ImmutableTable.Builder<String, String, AbstractUnit> builder =        units.builder();
    builder.put(unit1.getType(), unit1.getName(), unit1);
    ...
    units = builder.build();

I will get NPE when gettinb units.values(). Also, will I be able to modify values of AbstractUnit in the table?

Comment: I have a set of unit tests that started to fail when I changed to ImmutableTable. I have User that has all the data and Service that does the operations. I initialize the Table in the Service and set the value there [Service has Table = user.getUnits()]. It has all the data then, but at some point the value of Table becomes null. What may be missing?

Comment: If the `Table` becomes null, then you have to be setting it to null somewhere -- there's no other possibility.  Try marking the table variable as `final` so it can't be changed.

Comment: I cannot do that with my application. I think that ImmutableTable is simply not a solution for my problem - Issue 497 mentioned by Mike is exactly what I need. Till [if ever] that is implemented, I will have to make my own custom solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since Guava 20.0, [HashBasedTable](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) maintains insertion order. Specifically:

> Implementation of Table using linked hash tables. This guarantees predictable iteration order of the various views.

Internally it's backed by a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).